# Convert function base view to class base view in Django

Tags: django-views

how to convert these View to Class Base View, this view for add order new order and I wanna
change this View to Class Base but I cant

def add_user_order(request):

```
  new_order_form = UserNewOrderForm(request.POST or None)


  if new_order_form.is_valid():
        order = Order.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id, is_paid=False).first()
        if order is None:
            order = Order.objects.create(owner_id=request.user.id, is_paid=False)
        product_id = new_order_form.cleaned_data.get('product_id')
        count = new_order_form.cleaned_data.get('count')
        if count < 0:
            count = 1
        product = Product.objects.get_by_id(product_id=product_id)
        order.orderdetail_set.create(product_id=product.id, price=product.price, count=count)
    # todo: redirect user to user panel
        return redirect(f'products/{product_id}/{product.title.replace(" ", "-")}')

return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Please do not use `.replace(' ', '-')` to construct slugs: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/manually-constructing-a-slug.html

Comment: Can you also share the models you use here in this view?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a [**`FormView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) where the `form_valid` function will do most of the logic:

```
class UserAddOrderView(FormView):
    form_class = UserNewOrderForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        order, __ = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner_id=request.user.id, is_paid=False)
        self.product_id = product_id = new_order_form.cleaned_data.get('product_id')
        count = new_order_form.cleaned_data.get('count')
        if count < 0:
            count = 1
        order.orderdetail_set.create(product_id=product_id, price=product.price, count=count)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return f'products/{product_id}/{product.title.replace(" ", "-")}'
```

It is however *not* a good idea to construct URLs manually. You can work with the [**`reverse(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse). The same with slugs, do *not* construct slugs yourself, but use [**`slugify(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify). You should normally also save the slug to the model to which it belongs to make (fast) lookups possible.